# Hibernate: Exception occurred in target VM: failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I have `User` to `Cars` 1-to-n.
mappings:

*User*:

```
<set inverse="true" name="cars" table="CAR">
      <key>
        <column name="UserID" not-null="false"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="entity3.Car"/>
</set>
```

*Car:*

```
<many-to-one class="entity3.User"  name="user">
      <column name="UserID" not-null="false"/>
</many-to-one>
```

After i get some users and close session, in debugger, in `user` i see `PersistentSet cars` with this exception as value:

```
>Exception occurred in target VM: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entity3.User.cars, no session or session was closed 
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entity3.User.cars, no session or session was closed
```

Is this normal behavior? Do those exceptions slow down perfomance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this exception because the session that has been used to fetch the User entity has been closed (more probably it must have been destroyed somewhere in the code). 
If you need to fetch the Cars collection you will have to make sure that you have the same session open when you try to access the Cars property in the User entity.

I have also fallen once in this pitfall.

I don't think that exceptions itself causes any performance issues.